# Looping over array of functions fails for single function in Python

Tags: python

Consider the following piece of code:

```
def integ(fncts, propagate, stpSz):
    conditions = propagate.copy()
    iterator = 0
    for i in fncts:
        conditions[iterator] = conditions[iterator] + stpSz *  i(0)
        iterator+=1

    return conditions
```

Where `fncts` is an array of functions, like this:

```
 f1 = lambda x: x
 f2 = lambda x: 2*x
 fncts = (f1, f2)
```

Problem is, the code above works for `length(fncts)`>1. However, if there is only one function, it fails. How I can make sure the code can be executed if the user inputs only one function?

Comment: How does it fail? What error do you get?

Comment: Please expand upon "it fails".  Is there a traceback?  If so, please add it to your question.  I suspect that you are calling `inteq` like this `integ((f1), propagate, stpSz)` instead of like this `integ((f1,), propagate, stpSz)`.  Note the comma after `f1`.  That makes it a tuple rather than just parenthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the user inputs `fncts = f`? You can either require the user to always a sequence, so `fncts = [f]` or `fncts = (f,)`, or check whether `callable(fncts)`; tuples and lists are not callable.

Comment: Turns out I could just solve it using `if len(fncts) > 1:`, but thanks for answering so I'll give you the credit!

Comment: @thomas:  If checking the length of `fncts` works, then this answer is incorrect.  All the answers here assume that you were passing a function instead of a tuple to `integ`.  However, taking length of a function gives a TypeError (e.g. `len(lambda:1)`, so the assumption was incorrect.  Next time please ask your question more precisely and respond to requests for clarification.  If something "fails" please explain the expected behavior or post a traceback.  You will get better answers that way.

Answer (score 1):

Either throw an error if the first argument is not a list (at least a length 1 list) or check to see if fncts is a single function, then wrap it in a list before operating on it.